# Regular Expression to check if decimal is between two numbers irrespective of number of digits after decimal point

Tags: java, regex

Can you help me with writing a Regular Expression ( I will use this in Pattern.compile in Java)?

My requirement is

```
Given a decimal, should check if the given decimal is between two numbers,

Example: Given Number 1 : 0, Number 2: 50
a) 0 - true
b) 51 - false
c) 50 - true
d) 10.25 - true
e) 10.2345 - true
```

I should verify irrespective of number of digits after decimal point.

Comment: IMHO, this does not look like a good use for regex.

Comment: Why is `if (value >= min && value <= max)` not satisfactory, where `value`, `min` and `max` are `double` variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, thought he downvoted based on opinion, so sorry.

Comment: Regular expressions are for text.  You are trying to check numbers.  Numbers are not text.  Therefore, don't use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be tricky to implement the generic solution, so I'll leave here the solution for your example and let you think of a generic solution for it.

Here's your regex: `(([0-4]{1}[0-9]{1})|((50){1}))(\.[0-9]+)*`

To turn it generic you just need to change the first part implementation to the numbers you want to use, you can do it using a loop to concat those groups (this is the first part: `([0-4]{1}[0-9]{1})|((50){1})`).

Comment: `{1}` is a non sense. Moreover, this regex matches `50.999` (`>50`) or `00.0.0.0.0.0.0` (not a decimal number)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure I am understanding the question properly, so I can't be 100% sure it will work for all cases, but here is what I have.

```
([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})|([0-9]*0\b)
```

a) 0 - true

b) 51 - false

c) 50 - true

d) 10.25 - true

e) 10.2345 - true

If "." is between 2 Numbers or ends with 0.

Here is the example: https://regex101.com/r/295QWt/1

So my other answer is if a number is between 2 different numbers. Actually in this case I don't think regex is that useful. Depending on the language using regex might even be slower.

```
if(value > min && value < max){return true;}
```

Comment: It works as I described, which is why I note I wasn't sure if I understood the question properly.

Comment: The question seems clear to me, they want to match decimal numbers between 0 and 50. Your regex matches `9990` but shouldn't and doesn't match `1.123456` but should. As you can see in the link I gave.

Comment: Yeah, I started to get that, but not sure why using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
^(?:[0-4]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|50(?:\.0+)?)$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/b4ZFnF/1)